# Converting BMPs to avi

Tags: windows, vbscript, bmp, mpeg, avi

I want to convert folders with video-frames in bitmaps into avi or mpeg files. I already have a VBScript which does a lot of stuff on those files, so it would be neat to integrate a functionallity to convert those folders automatically from my script. I can only find solutions that seem pretty low level and unfortunatley I don't know a whole lot about video file formats. What is the easiest approach to achieve that without reinventing the wheel? My problem is that there is seem to be so much information that I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualdub can do this.

If you want a code solution there is plenty of wrappers for [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)